# SQLXML Bulk Load or manual iteration?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, xml

I am looking to insert a 20-25MB xml file into a database on a daily basis. The issue is that each entry needs an extra column added with a calculated value. So what I am wondering is if the most efficient way to do this would be using the SQLXML Bulk Load tools after editing the xml file, running through the xml file and add the new column then loading each item, or using the Bulk Load followed  by going through the database adding the new column values.

Comment: Can you calculate the add field from the information in that row?  If so, I wouldn't store the calucalted value at all...load the file as is, and whenever you need to display that caluclated value, generate it with SQL in your select statements.

Comment: I can and this is what I was going to do but when I go to retrieve the values I want to be able to search the table by that calculated value.

Comment: You can use calculations in your where statement (use 'having' if you're filtering by an aggregate like sum or average).  You won't be able to index this value though...were you looking to index it?

Comment: No I do not want to index the value. I did not know this about sql I should be able to just do that then. And just use the bulk load. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the calculated field as a computed column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments = answer

There is no need to store this value seperate.  Since it's a calculated value with the data you need to calculate it on each record, you can calculate this on the fly instead of storing it as it's own unique value.  A mix of where and/or having clauses will allow for filtering (searching) of results based on that calculated value.